# Is there any way to get pending migrations before running "typeorm migration:run"?

Tags: migration, nestjs, typeorm

I'm running this lines on my nest application:

```ts
import * as typeOrm from "../node_modules/typeorm/index";

bootstrap(){

    // ...

    const typeOrmConnection = typeOrm.getConnection();
    typeOrmConnection.runMigrations();
    logger.debug("Pending migrations executed");

}
```

This is executing successfully the pending migrations, but I would like to print them on log trace before/after **"runMigrations()"**, is there any way to do it?

I tried to get the return of:

```ts
const executedMigrations = await typeOrmConnection.runMigrations();
```

But I receive nothing.

Comment: Hi, you should not import a module directly from `node_module` instead use `import * as typeORM from 'typeorm';`.

Comment: You're right! Actually I changed after I posted this question, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was actually a bug in typeorm's code. It's already solved and you can get the pending migrations with:

```
await new MigrationExecutor(connection, connection.createQueryRunner('master')).getPendingMigrations()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [MigrationExecutor](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/90b406581d55223afa4472eb812d7f9ed2dce73c/src/migration/MigrationExecutor.ts) for retrieving all pending migrations:

```ts
await new MigrationExecutor(connection, connection.createQueryRunner('master')).getPendingMigrations()
```

Comment: This is loading all migration scripts in /migrations, it doesn't filter just the "pending"!

Comment: When you look at the [source code](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/c0c8566d6fde6c3a794798d4dc9c27f20cbac762/src/migration/MigrationExecutor.ts#L88) it does exactly as the name says: It returns all pending migrations that aren't applied yet. It is relying on a autogenerated `migration` table in your database. Perhaps it is corrupt?

Comment: That's what I thought, but I think there is a bug on the code. Actually it's not filtering, I've opened an issue on typeOrm repository: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/5425 thanks mate!

Answer (score 4):

To answer your Question I was in a similar situation today so I did a personal check

All you need is to run this in your terminal it shows all pending migrations and existing ones

`npx typeorm migration:show`

[image: Example Image of migrations including Pending Migrations]
This is an Example of what you get displayed the one with `[X]` is the one that has been migrated the one with `[ ]` is the pending one

**Migrations Ran**: `[X] updatePermissionsColumnToBusinessTable1628115737581`

**Migrations Pending**:`[ ] addMetadataToOrders1637614561828`

**Executable SQL queries**

```sql
SELECT * FROM "information_schema"."tables" WHERE "table_schema"=current_schema() AND "table_name" ='migrations';
SELECT * FROM "migrations" "migrations" ORDER BY "id" DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was actually asking about how to do that in my main.ts code of my nestjs project.

As I firstly thought, there was a bug in typeorm's code that I already reported. They just needed to add a "!" in their code. Now with "getPendingMigrations" you actually get the pending migrations.